# how to use automapper for delete action in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have used domain models in Views before. Now i just started creating ViewModels and used automapper to map the domain models to view models. I am new to automapper and have read few tutorials about it today.

After converting few code, i have my Post action on Delete as below. It looks quite funny to me. I am wondering 'if i am overusing Automapper'? Do i really need to use automapper on a post action like this as there are no binding and the only parameter is Id?

I have seen [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639618/CRUD-Opearations-using-AutoMapper-in-an-MVC-Applic) and the guy doesn't not use Automapper on Post action. I just wonder if i am defeating the purpose of having automapper.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>();
        CategoryViewModel category = Mapper.Map<Category, CategoryViewModel>(res.GetCategoryById(id));

        Mapper.CreateMap<CategoryViewModel, Category>();
        res.RemoveCategory(Mapper.Map<CategoryViewModel, Category>(category));
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, what you're doing is a pointless exercise.  You only need to use the primary key to delete an entity, and you certainly don't need to map any values to/from it because you're about to delete it.

Comment: One other thing, don't put CreateMap inside your controller actions. It only needs to get called once per AppDomain. Put those in one spot, like in your global.asax.